# Can ServiceStack Validators emit field names in camel case?

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

Is there a way to force service stack validators using the fluent validation plugin to emit the field name properties in camel case? I have configured the

```
 JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
```

so that my typescript types are in camel case, but all validation messages/errors come through in PascalCase. I would really like to keep camelCase in my json responses, but I would sure like the convenience of having field names that match up with the error message field names. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not really following, when `EmitCamelCaseNames = true` the returned JSON uses camelCase property names but the data remains in PacalCase to match up with the Request DTO property names, e.g:

```
{
  "responseStatus": {
    "errorCode": "InclusiveBetween",
    "message": "'Age' must be between 1 and 120. You entered 0.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "errorCode": "InclusiveBetween",
        "fieldName": "Age",
        "message": "'Age' must be between 1 and 120. You entered 0.",
        "meta": {
          "PropertyName": "Age",
          "From": "1",
          "To": "120",
          "Value": "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What JSON response has the issue?

Comment: Well, all of the JSON responses that have validation errors have this issue with the Field Name and the meta  PropertyName being in Pascal case. This is  just an annoyance when consuming the dtos from a javascript client in the browser. We have a coding convention to use camelCased objects, so we emit all our types in camelCase by turning EmitCamelCaseNames == true. We also need to support c# clients so I can see why it might not be good to globally change the property names in the data to pascal case. We might just have to forgo our coding standard and live with PascalCase in the dtos.

Comment: @on3al the camelCase convention just affects property names, it doesn't affect the data contained within it. It's Pascal case in the [Meta Dictionary](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/8ecf9df8c19b55c3b5a76341f29215b37d6d0a9c/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ResponseStatus.cs#L73) because it's a dictionary and the key is also data.